# How do I edit my Profile that is associated with User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes, url-routing, link-to

I created the model User and the model Profile. On my homepage I have a link in the dropmenu navigation bar that links to Edit Profile. **The problem I face is "No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]".**

The route for edit page is "edit_profile_path" with verb GET and URI pattern "/profiles/:id/edit(.:format)". I am having a hard time getting the "id" inserted. Below is the code that I have on my app.

**In model Profile file I have:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**In model User file I have:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

The profile has many attributes, but one of them is "user_id" which is an integer that is equal to the User's id. So User #5 with id#5 is the owner of Profile#5. 
**Here is the code that I have in the View file:**

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_profile_path(@profile) %></li>
```

With regards to the code directly above, I have tried inserting different codes inside the parenthesis, from @profile.id, @profile, @user.id, and @user. But it has not worked.

**I created a profiles controller and I think (but I am not certain) that my problem is coming from the profiles_controller file.** Here is the code that I have:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    @profile.user_id = current_user.id
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to welcome_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @profile.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to welcome_path
  end

    private
      def set_profile
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because in your view, your `@profile` in `nil`.
So, you have to get the `current_profile` in your view so that you can go to the edit page of that profile.

If you already have access to your `current_user` helper method, then, in your view, you can simply do:

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) %></li>
```

Comment: Thank you @KMRakibul! I appreciate you helping me out. The current_user method works!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note (which may be the key to solving your problem).

1. You are having a 1 to 1 relationship, and the user can access his profile only when he is logged in. Since you already have a (presumably properly working) `current_user` method, use it all the time.

   `def new
    current_user.build_profile
   end`

   `def create
    current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
    #etc
    end`
2. It's also a logical way to get the user's profile

   `private
         def set_profile
           @profile = current_user.profile
         end`

   In your view:

   `<%= link_to edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) %>`

I think this makes much more sense in your code and is much more readable. Additionally, I think such approach will save you a lot of errors such as the one you're encountering now.

Comment: Thank you @Hristo! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I used your advice to use current_user and I applied it to the route. My app now allows Users to edit their profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
 edit_profile_path(id: @profile.id)
```

Also did you put this route in your routes file?

Comment: Thank you @JohnPollard! I ended up using edit_profile_path(current_user.id). I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.